# Summing to columns into a third column in SSRS

Tags: sql, reporting-services, ssrs-2017

I have two columns in.column1, ou.column2. I would like to place a third column next to them that totals the number from both columns. I have tried an expression=sum(Fields!in.coulmn1.value,"new_dataset") +(Fields!in.coulmn2.value,"new_dataset")this does not give me the correct answer. Any help appreciated!

When trying the above expression I get a total that does not equal the total of the two columns.

Comment: remove the dataset scope (`, "new_dataset"`) from your expression. Is the scope is not specified then the scope of the row is used, so it will work it it's a single row of the grouped sum of multiple rows.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is summing all records in the dataset.  If you just want totals per row, try removing the Sum call.  Something like...

```
= Fields!in.column1.value + Fields!in.column2.value
```